# Images are not being stored in folder in Laravel

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

I have a form in which when a user fills the form and submits, the data is gone to the database and my mail id, below is my controller

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\SendEmail;
use App\Register;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Mail;
use Session;
use Storage;

class RegController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = new Register;
        $data->firstname = $request->firstname;
        $data->lastname = $request->lastname;
        $data->mobilenumber = $request->mobilenumber;
        $data->experience = $request->experience;
        $data->designation = $request->designation;
        $data->confirmation = $request->confirmation;
        $data->company = $request->company;
        $data->address = $request->address;
        $data->addressline2 = $request->addressline2;
        $data->city = $request->city;
        $data->state = $request->state;
        $data->pin = $request->pin;
        $data->country = $request->country;
        $data->Whatsapp = $request->Whatsapp;
        $data->alternatenumber = $request->alternatenumber;
        $data->Email = $request->Email;
        $data->CompanyRegNumber = $request->CompanyRegNumber;
        $data->Date_Incorporation_orBusi_Stp = $request->Date_Incorporation_orBusi_Stp;
        $data->GSTIN = $request->GSTIN;
        $data->Services_Offered = $request->Services_Offered;
        $data->Annual_Turnover = $request->Annual_Turnover;
        $data->Declaration = $request->Declaration;
        $data->Fee = $request->Fee;
        $data->termsandconditions = $request->termsandconditions;
        $data->Mode_of_Payment = $request->Mode_of_Payment;
        $data->Recommended_by_A = $request->Recommended_by_A;
        $data->Recommended_by_B = $request->Recommended_by_B;

        if ($request->hasFile('Photo')) {
            $image = $request->file('Photo');
            $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Photo');
            Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, File::get($image));
            $data->Photo = $filename;
        }
        if ($request->hasFile('Receipt')) {
            $image = $request->file('Receipt');
            $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Receipt');
            Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, File::get($image));
            $data->Receipt = $filename;
        }
        if ($request->hasFile('Signature')) {
            $image = $request->file('Signature');
            $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Signature');
            Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, File::get($image));
            $data->Signature = $filename;
        }

        $data->save();
        Session::flash('registered', 'reg');

        $name = $request->firstname." ".$request->lastname;
        $subject = "TEIA";
        $message = $data->id;
        $photo = $data->Photo;
        $sign = $data->Signature;
        $recipt = $data->Receipt;
        $email = 'teiamembers@gmail.com';

        // ->cc(['name1@domain.com','name2@domain.com'])
        Mail::to($email)->send(new SendEmail($subject, $message, $photo, $sign, $recipt));

        return redirect('formdata');
    }
}
```

my database fields

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7ncX.png)

I have done the following code to display the values in PHP

```html
<?php
$servername = "moluguz.accountsupportmysql.com";
$username = "teia";
$password = "bolsterking";
$dbname = "teia";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * from registers ORDER BY ID DESC limit 1 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!empty($result) && $result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
```

in the email I am getting all the data including the image..but in the HTML website when I am trying to display the values, all the data except the image is being displayed, and when I am checking the uploads folder, no images are being stored . can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code...?

Answer (score 0):

Your image is not visible because, In your database you are storing only filename of image.

To upload image try below:

you can configure your file upload path in 'config/filesystem.php' file.

In your code you are using 'public' disk so in your filesystem.php file make below change:

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ]
```

you can upload file with below code:

```
$image = $request->file('photo');
$filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
Storage::disk('public')->put('uploads/Photo/'.$filename, $image);
```

This upload your file in 'Storage/app/public/uploads/Photo' folder.

To access file from storage folder you need to create symbolic link in public folder. you can create it with command:
    'php artisan storage:link'

You can check laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem)

I hope it will help.

Comment: why is it app\public? my images are stored in root folder named public..

Comment: in your filesystem.php file change [ 'root' => public_path()]. It will upload your image to root public directory.

Comment: the image is being stored but this error is being thrown Unable to open file for reading [/hermes/walnaweb08a/b1307/as.book/TEIA/storage/app/public/1562913994bannernew.jpg]

Comment: It seems like it is still looking for file into to storage folder. in your filesystem.php file change [ 'url' => env('APP_URL')] and make sure you have set 'APP_URL' env variable.